# Visual Studio Addin - Get Name\Path of binary of a c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, add-in

I want to get the binary name of a C++ Project with a Visual Studio C# Addin.

I googled and found, that the the EnvDTE.Configuration.properties should have a element called "AssemblyName" but C++ projects do not seem to have this element.

Did somebody know where could I get this information inside a visual studio addin?

Comment: C++ projects don't have 'assemblies' like C# projects do. What, exactly, do you mean by 'assembly?'

Comment: Hey,ok thats right. I want to know the name of the bin. The dll or exe with it path.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve this with $(OutputPath) and $(TargetName).

Comment: How could I resolve these macros inside a addin?

Comment: Googling i found http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms228958.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VC++ projects you need to get access to the `VCConfiguration` object which you should be able to get at from the `EnvDTE.Project`'s `Object` property like:

```
EnvDTE.Project project = ...
VCProject vcProj = (VCProject)project.Object;
IVCCollection configs = (IVCCollection)vcProj.Configurations;
VCConfiguration config = (VCConfiguration)configs.Item(configName); // like "Debug"
```

At that point with the `VCConfiguration` how exactly to get at the correct properties depends on your set up.  You can access the the `VCLinkerTool` from the `Tools` property and get at the `OutputFile` and other properties.  Or, if you use the newer inherited property sheets you may access those through the `Rules` property.

```
IVCCollection tools = (IVCCollection)config.Tools;
VCLinkerTool linkTool = (VCLinkerTool)tools.Item("Linker Tool");
string outputFile = linkTool.OutputFile;

// -------

IVCRulePropertyStorage ruleStorage = config.Rules.Item(ruleName);
string outputFile = ruleStorage.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("TargetName");
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the complete path of the binary, follow the steps as @Chadwick said to get the `VCConfiguration` object. And then, just use the following line of code:

```
//returns the complete binary name including path as a string
var primaryOutput = config.PrimaryOutput;
```